# Angular Translate Unit Test - Can't inject $translateProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, es6-modules

I'm using ES6, AngularJS, Karma/Jasmine, and angular-translate. Can't seem to get my unit test to pass. Not really too sure how to work with 3rd party modules, like angular-translate, when it comes to unit testing. The code and the error I'm getting are below. $translateProvider is not loading.

```
import CatalogueModule from './catalogue.module'
import CatalogueService from './catalogue.service'

let service,
    _$translateProvider;

describe('CatalogueService', () => {
  beforeEach(angular.mock.module(CatalogueModule));

  beforeEach(() => {
    angular.mock.module({
      $translateProvider: jasmine.createSpyObj('$translateProvider',
        ['translations', 'preferredLanguage']
      ),
      $translate: jasmine.createSpyObj('$translate',
        ['use']
      )
    });
  })

  beforeEach(inject(($translateProvider) => {
    _$translateProvider = $translateProvider;

    _$translateProvider.translations('en', {});
    _$translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');

    // service = new CatalogueService();
  }));

  it('should set the config object after initialization', inject(($translateProvider, CatalogueService) => {
    // $translateProvider.use.and.returnValue();
    // expect(service.config.headers).to.equal(null);
  }));
});
```

This is the error:

```
✖ "before each" hook: WorkFn for "should set the config object after initialization"
      Chrome 59.0.3071 (Mac OS X 10.12.3)
    Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $translateProviderProvider <- $translateProvider
```

UPDATE - Adding catalogue.service.js

```
class CatalogueService {
  constructor($http, $q, $translate) {
    'ngInject';

    this._$http      = $http;
    this._$q         = $q;
    this._$translate = $translate;

    this.config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Accept': '******',
        'P3-APP-ID': '*****',
        'P3-Date': '*****'
      }
    };

    this.catalogue = this.getCatalogue();
  }

  getCatalogue() {
    const lang = this._$translate.use();
    const url = `https://somedomain.com/catalog?language_code=${lang}`;
    const deferred = this._$q.defer();

    this._$http
      .get(url, this.config)
      .then(
        (res) => deferred.resolve(res.data.characters),
        (err) => deferred.reject(err)
      );

    return deferred.promise;
  };

  getCharacterByCharId(charId) {
    return this.catalogue
      .then((res) => {
        return res.find((character) => {
          return character.link_name === charId;
        });
      });
  };
}

export default CatalogueService;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.module(...))
```

in the test. Which means that only `ng` and `ngMock` modules are loaded in current test, and there is no `$translateProvider` service.

It is preferable to test Angular units by instantiating them with DI, not directly. This allows to test both service annotation and class internals.

It is highly desirable to keep unit tests isolated and eliminate every unit but tested one from the test, especially third-party libraries. If tested units require `$translateProvider`, it should be preferably be replaced with a mock or a stub:

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.module('moduleThatContainsCatalogueService');

beforeEach(() => {
  angular.mock.module({
    $translateProvider: jasmine.createSpyObj('$translateProvider',
      ['translations', 'preferredLanguage', 'use']
    )
  });
})

it('...', inject(($translateProvider, catalogueService) => {
  $translateProvider.use.and.returnValue(...);
  ...
}));
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Got it to work with your suggestion. I've also updated my question to include my CatalogueService service which uses $translate. The issue is that now I'm getting the following error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'use' of undefined

Comment: Basically, $translate isn't being set or passed in as a DI in the CatalogueService.

Comment: You can choose to either pass all dependencies manually with `new` or use DI to instantiate it. The second option is more preferable since you need to test DI annotation any way for full coverage.

Answer (score 0):

I've accomplished this using a custom loader for `$translateProvider` before. This example is in typescript but something like this should work for you as well:

```
angular.mock.module(($provide: angular.auto.IProvideService, translateProvider: angular.translate.ITranslateProvider) => {
    $provide.factory('customLoader', ($q: angular.IQService) => 
        () => {
            const deferred = $q.defer();
            deferred.resolve({});
            return deferred.promise;
    });

    $translateProvider.useLoader('customLoader');
});
```